# How can I animate MatrixTransform.Matrix at center?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I am developing a WPF application that allows the user to use multi-touch to manipulate an image using the `MatrixTransform.Matrix` on `RenderTransform`. Using [this very helpful snippet of code](http://pwlodek.blogspot.com/2010/12/matrixanimation-for-wpf.html), I was able to animate it with a storyboard created in C#.

The trouble is that `currentItem` seems to always rotate and scale in relation to the top left hand corner.

How can I make it so it rotates around the center of the `FrameworkElement`?

Here is what I have so far, a basic example of using the animation:

```
Matrix fromMatrix = ((MatrixTransform)currentItem.RenderTransform).Matrix;

Matrix toMatrix = new MatrixTransform().Matrix;
//Making sure location of the toMatrix is in the same place as the fromMatrix
toMatrix.OffsetX = fromMatrix.OffsetX;
toMatrix.OffsetY = fromMatrix.OffsetY;

MatrixAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new MatrixAnimation();
myDoubleAnimation.From = fromMatrix;
myDoubleAnimation.To = toMatrix;

myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5));

Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
myStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);
Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation, currentItem);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(MatrixTransform.Matrix)"));
myStoryboard.Begin(this);
```

I feel as though I need to add or subtract from the `fromMatrix.OffsetY` and `fromMatrix.OffsetX`. I have tried doing this with half the width/height of the `currentItem`, but this either puts it rotating and scaling around the center *(good)* **OR** twice as far away from the center *(twice as bad)*, depending on which way I have the `currentItem` turned when it begins to animate.

Answer (score 0):

Super late answer here - but I believe you just use the XAML attribute

`RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"`

Place that on your XAML where the Transform is applied. Not really sure you need to do that in code-behind unless you built up that object in code.

Reference: [RenderTransformOrigin from MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin?view=net-5.0)